# Jquery Script Not Causing Any Interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery script that I just wrote up real fast to fill up a p class so that options for server interaction can be easily switched from player to server etc 
etc. The problem I'm having now is my script does not fill whatsoever. I have a form that works with ajax right over it, so I don't see why it would be a jquery lib issue. 
My non interactive supposed to be interactive script is as follows:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".commandclass").click(function(e){
        var url = $(".commandclass").attr("data-href");
        $(".commandtype").load(url);
    )};
});
</script>
```

And it's lovely counterparts (Okay, maybe we'll go with bearable counterparts) Are:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='commandclass' data-href='modules/server.submod.php'>Server Commands</a> | 
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='commandclass' data-href='modules/player.submod.php'>Player Commands</a> |
                        <p class='commandtype'>
                        <table align='center'>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 300' id='command' name='command'>5 Minute Restart</td>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 900' id='command' name='command'>15 Minute Restart</td>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 1800' id='command' name='command'>30 Minute Restart</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 3600' id='command' name='command'>1 Hour Restart</td>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 21600' id='command' name='command'>6 Hour Restart</td>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 43200' id='command' name='command'>12 Hour Restart</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td></td>
                                <td><input type='radio' value='server restart 86400' id='command' name='command'>1 Day Restart</td>
                            <td></td></tr>
                        </table>
                        </p>
```

So my desired output would be when you click on the link; rather than the link being followed it pulls from the data-href attribute I've attached and fills it into the commandtype p class so that it continues from there and loads said functions into the webpage.
Well. Not too sure what else would help, but feel free to ask if I missed any of that required information and I promise in turn. I'll slap myself upside the head or let my daughter do it for the blunder.

Thought that maybe this would help, so I'm adding this as well.
My top portion has two scripts. One for running the command one for switching different kinds inside the module. This is my top-most portion of it all.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
    $("#quickcommands").submit(function() {
        $(".result").html("Running Command");
        $(".result").append("<img src='/assets/images/giphy.gif'>");
       $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("#quickcommands").attr("action"),
    data: $("#quickcommands").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
                if(data == "") { $(".result").html("Command Sent"); }
    }
  });
  return false;
    });


  });


</script> 
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".commandclass").click(function(e){
        var url = $(".commandclass").attr("data-href");
        $(".commandtype").html("test");
    )};
});
</script>
```

The top script works just fine, It's on script number 2 where nothing seems to work.

Comment: What happens on the network?

Comment: You mean within the console debug?

Comment: What you have should work fine. Have you checked for errors in the console? Are the `.commandclass` elements appended to the page dynamically?

Comment: yeah, on the network tab

Comment: I actually haven't ever used that in Chrome. I always forget they exist, so I'm trying to find it now.Nothing actually happens within the console when I try to run it. And @RoryMcCrossan No. The `.commandclass` elements are hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo?

Towards the end there is a `)}` instead of `})`

Comment: Thanks JNF. That was it. Hate to say it, but I probably would have been bashing my head into a table trying to figure it out for hours, so thank you! The hangover provides all the headache I need in the morning!

Comment: I would be calling your daughter in... ;) That happens when you write code hastily. I've witnessed a colleague spend 3 hours on code to find a `=` instead of `==`

Comment: It's actually the first time I've wrote any javascript without looking at any references. I'm strong in PHP and weak in Janything.

Comment: @MorganGreen, on another note - get familiar with [devTools](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-devtools) and [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). The two tools which are invaluable when debugging this kind of thing, and consequently, what I used to track it down.

Comment: @JNF, Will do. I've never utilized devTools and I need to remember it's there and available.

Comment: @Shane_Yo - see my [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154549/jquery-script-not-causing-any-interaction/31154878?noredirect=1#comment50319128_31154890) below.

Comment: @JNF - noted thanx (played with this answer a bit at version 9) 
 https://jsfiddle.net/b8Lddphj/9/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your script to the following:

```
<script>
    $(".commandclass").click(function(e){
        var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
        $(".commandtype").load(url);
    });
</script>
```

The first change is that I've removed the wrapping anonymous function (also the braces seemed messed up a bit). The above code should be sufficient, unless you're creating the buttons dynamically. The second change is the `$(this)` - you have multiple `.commandclass` elements, and this change makes sure you select the value from the element on which the `click` event is triggered.

Comment: This could cause a problem of elements loading after script is run. That's why it's good practice to have the wrapping of anon function sent to jquery

Comment: Thanks Dropout, Well put together answer. `$(this)` seems to be pretty much the same thing, but it is prettier.

Comment: As for the anon function. I'm going to go ahead and leave it. I've never heard it's good practice to remove it.

Comment: @MorganGreen - actually it isn't. Out of the scope for this question, but you might notice both links carrying out the same function if you leave the class selector where it is. You do need the `this`.

Comment: Just saw that when I ran it this last time, so I'm glad it was pointed out. Didn't even know I had that problem, so it's good to know for sure.